# Why use a PCI System Timer?

Tags: voip, pci, asterisk

I have [heard it said](http://vicidial-hardware.5gigahertz.com/) that servers serving VOIP services such as Asterisk should use a [PCI System Timer](http://amfeltec.com/products/x1-pci-express-system-timer-2/). **Why?** Nowhere is this ever explained, and googling reveals no clear use-cases for the device.

**Why are these devices recommended, and how do they perform better than what is already on the motherboard?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern asterisk works same with pci card or without.

Thoose recomendation valid for linux kernel <2.6.18, that is not actual in modern distro.

Comment: Thank you! Is this documented anywhere, either in official Asterisk communications or elsewhere? How does a kernel change mitigate the lack of a dedicated hardware component?

Comment: You just need hi-resolution timer. Linux kernel since 2.6.18 provide Hi-res timer in default core. Most of distros now use 1khz timer(before was 80hz) nowdays. So very likly you distro also use 1000hz which is enought for voip. Before that you have get any card(used e1/t1 is also ok),because cards HAVE independend hi-res timer.

Comment: arheops is correct.  Dedicated timing devices are no longer necessary.  In fact, in modern asterisk, you do not even need any special kernel modules anymore. For a little history you can see: http://lists.digium.com/pipermail/asterisk-users/2012-September/274654.html and https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Timing+Interfaces .